# Text/Synonym recommendation api

Tags: azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services, text-analytics-api

In LUIS, we have text/synonym recommendation in the entity/phrase list generation. Do anyone have idea on the api that is used for the synonym recommendation. We wanted to integrate the cognitive service api to get the synonym of the input text in one of the client application but we could not get any relevant Microsoft service to attain this.

[I am unable to provide sample code because of the nature of the question]

[Luis Text Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-interchangeable-phrase-list)

[TextAnaytics API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/extract-key-phrases-from-text)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we don't have any API for synonym recommendation yet. You can request this as feature [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues).